# My database is connected, but I'm unable to pull data from the table I've created

Tags: php, database

My database connection works. I've tested it. However, when I try to pull data from the table in my database, I get "0 results". There are two rows of data in the table I created in the database. What am I missing?

Thanks. Here's the code:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "********";
$username = "********";
$password = "**********";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "SELECT Product_Name, Price, Product_No FROM Products";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Product Name: " . $row["Product_Name"]. " - Price: " . 
$row["Price"]. " " . $row["Product_No"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing fourth param in mysqli constructor, which is $database. So you're connected to the MySQL server, but didn't select database.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

And that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to select the database

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

should be

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);
```

or you can use

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn->select_db("world");
```